# How to pull the worksheet name from an externally-referenced cell in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, reference

How to pull the worksheet name from an externally-referenced cell in another worksheet

Cell `B1` in my worksheet `WS1` shows a value from a referenced cell `RefCell` in worksheet `WS2`.

How can I show which worksheet `RefCell` exists in in cell `A1` within `WS1`?

Something like this is what I need to happen:

```
 __________________________________
|_______|___A____|___B____|___C____|
|___1___|__Pets__|__Dog___|________|
|___2___|__Fruit_|__Apple_|________|

  *Column B contains referenced values from other worksheets (within the same workbook).
  *The value in Column A detects the worksheet name of the value in Column B.
```

Can this be achieved in VBA?  How would it be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) '<--| loop through column B cells with formulas found from row 2 down to last not empty one
        cell.Offset(, -1) = Split(Replace(cell.Formula, "=", ""), "!")(0) '<--| extract worksheet name out of current cell formula and write it in corresponding column A cell
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @SnookerFan, did you try this solution?

Comment: How would I implement this?  Would you be able to write it in full so that I can copy and paste it into my VBA editor to test it?

Comment: see edited (and commented) code. If it solves your question please mark this answer as accepted. thank you

Answer (score 0):

since the reference is stored as a formula in the cell.

ex the cell B2 would have  a formula of =pets!refcell

so what you can do is get the formula use instr funcion to get the length of sheet name and use left to get the sheet name and assign it to the cell

```
B_formaula= str(sheet1.range("B2").formula)
st_name=left(B_formula,instr(1,B_formula,"!",vbbinarycompare)-1)
sheet1.range("A2").value=st_name
```

i hope this helps.

```
sub st_name()
dim ws as worksheet
set ws=thisworkbook.sheets(1)
irow=ws.range("B1:B"& rows.count).end(xlup).row
for i = 1 to irow
B_formaula= str(ws.range("B"& i).formula)
st_name=left(B_formula,instr(1,B_formula,"!",vbbinarycompare)-1)
ws.range("A"& i).value=st_name
next i
end sub
```

this subroutine will check all the values in b column from row no  1 to last row and add the sheet name to the column A.

I havent tested the code yet. try the code if any error revert back.

Comment: This seems like it could work, but I can't implement it in VBA.  How exactly would it be written?  (Function/Sub?)

Comment: are the values already there in the b column.... or they should also be copied using vba?

Comment: The values are already in the column (I used a named range `NamedRange`).  I want column A to pick out the worksheet value of the cell in column B.

Comment: if the values are there already and if you have do this for all the values in b -column you can have a for loop within the code.

Comment: if you are using a namedrange then you can use for each cell in the namedrange instead of the ist row to last row

Comment: I see.  And how exactly would I write/structure that code in my VBA editor?  I've not written a VBA function for Excel before so am not sure where to start.  Do I write it under a `Private Sub` / something else?

Comment: its the sub routine i gave you....if you want the loop to work for a named range. dim cell as range. then at the for condition use for each cell in range("Range_name"), and then while referencing cells use cell and cell offset to get the value . at the end loop it with next cell